# Como imprimir os dois valores do vetor no struct com ponteiro?

Tags: c, struct

Fiz um código com `struct Pessoa` para guardar mais de uma nota e imprimir usando ponteiro. Minha dúvida: como faço para imprimir na função `listar()` as duas notas que registrei na função `main()`? Estou fazendo do jeito certo?

Coloquei as duas notas no primeiro índice [0] para ter a possibilidade de testar a função apenas.

Quero listar as notas da pessoa cadastrada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct pessoa{
    int notas[4];
};

void listar(struct pessoa *n1){
    int cont=0;
    for(cont=0;cont<2;cont++){
        printf("\n--Nota:");
        //Duvida aqui:
        printf("%d",(*(n1 + cont)->notas));

    }

}

main(){
    printf("\n Digite a nota:");
    struct pessoa n1[10];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        printf("\nDigite a nota:");
        scanf("%d",&n1[0].notas[i]);
    }
    listar(n1); 
}
```

Comment: Se notas é um array de 4 posições você precisa imprimir elemento a elemento do array e não da maneira como fez.

Comment: E você quer listar o que? as pessoas e suas notas ou só as notas pessoas cadastrada?

Comment: Eu faço isso com o " * "? Eu não sei ao certo, eu tentei colocar *(n1)->notas[cont], mas não sei

Comment: Eu quero listar as notas da pessoa cadastrada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entendo que queira passar a struct por referência, evita redundâncias e optimiza o código, porém a notação *(ptr + pos) é equivalente à ptr[pos] em C... ou seja, você está tentando acessar um endereço de memória que não foi designado, caso queira imprimir todas as notas de um único aluno você deverá iterar pelo array notas, não pessoa

```
for (int i = 0; i < numNotas; i++) {
    printf("%d ", pessoa.notas[i]);
}
```

Na forma que está recebendo um ponteiro na função além de ser uma boa prática pois está passando o dado por referência ganhas a possibilidade de listar as notas de n alunos, eu a escreveria da seguinte forma:

```
void listar(struct pessoa *pessoas, int numPessoas, int numNotas) {
      for (int i = 0; i < numPessoas; i++) {
         printf("Aluno %d:", i+1);
         for (int j = 0; j < numNotas; j++) {
            printf(" %d", pessoas[i].notas[j]);
         }
         printf("\n");
      }
   }
```

Comment: Para acessar o conteúdo de um ponteiro, não precisa do *?

Comment: Neste caso não pois a notação ptr[i] = *(ptr + i), caso 'pessoas' tenha somente uma struct vc pode acessá-la tanto com *pessoas quanto com pessoas[0]

Answer (score 2):

Está fazendo algumas confusões aí. Se quer listar uma pessoa passe uma pessoa e não todas as pessoas. Aí tudo fica simples e fácil. Note que além de receber só uma pessoa estou passando uma como argumento, aquela que acabou de digitar. Com esse código nem poderia ser diferente.

Pode ser que até esteja querendo fazer outra coisa, mas dentro do colocado na pergunta seria isto.

Eu dei uma melhorada porque o código era muito confuso e complicado, preste atenção em cada detalhe.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct pessoa {
    int notas[4];
};

void listar(struct pessoa pessoa) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) printf("\n--Nota %d: %d", i + 1, pessoa.notas[i]);
}

int main() {
    struct pessoa n1[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("\nDigite a nota:");
        scanf("%d", &n1[0].notas[i]);
    }
    listar(n1[0]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/R0Hquf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/CorretParameterc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/CorrectParameter.c).

Comment: Já me ajudou, obrigado. Se possível, você consegue me ajudar a fazer a mesma coisa usando ponteiro? Imprimir a mesma coisa, só que com ponteiro na função Listar?

Comment: Não porque não faz sentido usar ponteiro ali.

Comment: Só se eu tivesse que listar as 10 pessoas junto com as notas?

Comment: Aí faria sentido.